# Phonegap 2.5.0 splash cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Hye, I know the problem have been asked several times, but I put splash.png in all my drawable folders and I still have this error.
I tried to clean my project, restart eclipse either my computer.
Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my error, in my class, I was importing android.R which is wrong.

My class was like :

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class myClass extends Activity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashimg);
```

Instead you should extends DroidGap which has its own R class, like this

```
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class myClass extends DroidGap{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashimg);
```

Hoping this will help someone else.